# Не работает скрипт в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

следовал одному тутору из ютуба и написал вот это:

```
public void OnFadeComplete()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
    StartCoroutine(Loading());
}

IEnumerator Loading()
{
    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneToLoad);
    loadingCanvas.SetActive(true);

    while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress);
        slider1.value = progress;
        slider2.value = progress;
        slider3.value = progress;
        loadingText.text = progress.ToString() + "%";
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Почему-то канвас не включается вообще, хотя в переменных все указано верно, буквально минут пять назад все работало, а потом что-то поламалось.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Проверьте, вызывается ли метод `OnFadeComplete()` в вашем коде. Может
   случиться так, что этот метод больше не вызывается по какой-то
   причине.
2. Указан ли правильный сценарий для загрузки в переменной sceneToLoad?
   Если указана неверная сцена, то метод `LoadSceneAsync` не будет
   работать корректно.
3. Убедитесь, что вы выставили переменную `loadingCanvas` в редакторе
   Unity и что объект, на который она указывает, не выключен.
4. Проверьте, указаны ли в редакторе **Unity** все ссылки на `slider1`,
   `slider2`, `slider3` и `loadingText`.
5. Обратите внимание на очерёдность выполнения методов. Вы вызываете
   метод `LoadScene(sceneToLoad)` перед стартом `Loading()`. Это
   немедленно загрузит новую сцену и выключит текущую, включая все
   объекты на ней, до того как `Loading()` начнёт выполнение.
   Вам нужно либо убрать вызов SceneManager.`LoadScene(sceneToLoad);` из
   `OnFadeComplete()`, либо вызвать `StartCoroutine(Loading());` перед ним.
6. Проверьте логи Unity на наличие ошибок. Возможно, при изменении кода
   или сцены возникла новая ошибка, которая прерывает выполнение
   скрипта.
7. Если у вас есть система, которая отвечает за переключение сцен и
   fade анимацию, убедитесь, что она корректно работает и не выключает
   канвас в процессе выполнения.
8. Убедитесь, что `Loading()` действительно запускается. Вы
   можете добавить в неё `Debug.Log`, чтобы удостовериться.